# Pass environmental variables by reference from one to another batch file

Tags: batch-file, pass-by-reference

I'm in this situation where I have one batch file which creates a bunch of variables, then starts (with `start /w "file.batch"`) another batch file that uses and modifies the variables from the first batch file.

Now this works fine until the second file closes itself and returns to the first file, because the variables that were modified by the second file are not references to, but actually copy's of the original variables, meaning that they were no longer linked to the original variables. This renders the second script practically useless.

I know that `call "file.batch"` would run the second file in the same environment, which would fix the problem, but I want the second file to run in a separate window, which `call "file.batch"` doesn't.

Here's a quick demonstration of the problem:

File 1:

```
@echo off
set $var=0
echo before starting file 2: %$var%
start test02.bat
echo after starting file 2: %$var%
echo before calling file 2: %$var%
call test02.bat
echo after calling file 2: %$var%
pause&exit
```

File 2:

```
@echo off
echo inside file 2: %$var%
set $var=1
echo inside file 2: %$var%
exit /b 0
```

Output:

```
before starting file 2: 0
```

```
inside file 2: 0
inside file 2: 1
```

```
after starting file 2: 0
before calling file 2: 0
inside file 2: 0
inside file 2: 1
after calling file 2: 1
```

Comment: No. There is not. This is well known.

Comment: Well.. The only way would be to loop it to check if the second batch is running, if not, start it and only then echo stuff, but that is really alot of work compared to where you could just call the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll to do it by storing all the echo'd text in an array so when a part of the console has to be cleared, the text above it can be restored